# How to create user in Openfire from java?

Tags: openfire

I want to create user and register that user to roster from my  `java application` manually to  `openfire server` .

Is there any way or any example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the REST API from Openfire for that.

How to create a new user: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-user

How to add a roster entry: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-user-roster-entry

You can download REST API Plugin here: http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp

Official JAVA implementation: https://github.com/igniterealtime/REST-API-Client

Comment: I don't have any Idea how to use them in my application, can you provide an example?

Comment: In the mean time is also an official Java implementation available: https://github.com/igniterealtime/REST-API-Client with maven support

Comment: @RomanS.Is there a javascript Library to create a web app which uses Openfire for chatting?

Comment: Not a framework, but an API: https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/openfire-chat-api/68792
(I'm not sure how stable it is)